# math range error in scipy minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to fit six parameters to very ugly distribution function with maximum likelihood method. For this purpose, I try to use `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

Here is piece of code

```
import math
form scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

#generate some data
xdata = np.random.lognormal(0,1,812)
#function for the Log likelihood
def mfpdf2(params):
    c1 = params[0]
    A1 = params[1]
    a1 = params[2]
    c2 = params[3]
    A2 = params[4]
    a2 = params[5]

    LL_vec = [math.log(c1*(math.exp(-A1*x) - math.exp(-a1*x))+c2*(math.exp(-A2*x) - math.exp(-a2*x))) for x in xdata]
    LL = -sum(LL_vec)


return LL

#try to find max likelihood (minimize negative loglikelihood)

start_params = [1,1,2,1,1,2]

pars = minimize(mfpdf2, start_params)
```

This piece of code returns me an error:

```
File "C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/python/pokusy_analyza_multiexp.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
LL_vec = [math.log(c1*(math.exp(-A1*x) - math.exp(-a1*x))+c2*(math.exp(-A2*x) - math.exp(-a2*x))) for x in xdata]

ValueError: math domain error
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: Your PDF is not normalized.  The integral of a PDF over the domain must be 1.  This will cause a problem when you try to minimize the neg. log-likelihood.  The objective function might not have a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are probably doing a log of a negative number which is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your expression inside the `math.log` function will return a negative number if `x` is negative. the logarithm of a negative number is only defined for complex numbers, so the regular log function will give you a `ValueError: math domain error`. You can convert `x_data` to complex numbers and use `np.log` if that will produce acceptable results from `minimize` wit your particular application:

```
xdata = np.random.lognormal(0,1,812).astype(np.complex)
...
LL_vec = [np.log(c1*(math.exp(-A1*x) - m ...
```

Or you can specify a different minimization technique (not all support defined bounds) and specify bounds on the values. This does not support symbolic bounds like `A1 > a1` so you must re-order your variables a bit to make the relation:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

xdata = np.random.lognormal(0,1,812)

def mfpdf2(params):

    c1 = params[0]
    A1 = params[1]
    offset1 = params[2] #this can obviously be condensed to one line
    a1 = A1 + offset1 #bound offset to be positive so a is always > A 
    c2 = params[3]
    A2 = params[4]
    offset2 = params[5]
    a2 = A2 + offset2

    LL_vec = [np.log(
                     c1*(np.exp(-A1*x) - np.exp(-a1*x))+
                     c2*(np.exp(-A2*x) - np.exp(-a2*x))
                 ) for x in xdata]
    #this will not account for the possibility that 
    #   one of c1*(...) or c2*(...) is negative but 
    #   the sum is still positive. This could conceiveably 
    #   be achieved with more ratios or offsets instead of 
    #   direct values, but would make the math real nasty.
    LL = -sum(LL_vec)
    return LL

start_params = [1,1,2,1,1,2]
pars = minimize(mfpdf2, 
                start_params, 
                method='L-BFGS-B',
                #now define your bounds
                bounds=((None, None), # c1
                        (None, None), # A1
                        (0, None),    # a1 - A1 (makes a1 always larger than A1)
                        (None, None), # c2
                        (None, None), # A2
                        (0, None)))   # a2
```

Comment: Pretty sure [log-normally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distributed values are always positive.  The problem comes more if the optimization routine drives the `a` values to be smaller than the `A` values, which will also return negatives in the `log`.

Comment: This is it, but how can I set the condition that A is always smaller than a?

Comment: If you do use complex numbers does it converge on the value you're looking for?

Comment: @Bobesh edited to make it look like I didn't initially forget how lognormal plots looked xD does this help?